# Creating a new table along with join statements in Run SQL in IBM dashDB

Tags: sql, dashdb

I'm new with SQL and I'm trying to create a new table after joining two tables with different fields except for the primary id. I saw online that it is possible, but IBM's dashDB's Run SQL doesn't seem to like it as it marks it as "'with_data_or_definitions_only' expected after this token" right after the parenthesis. I'm not entirely sure what exactly this error is and how I can fix it as after looking over it online, my code's almost similar in syntax. I'm thinking that dashDB might have a different syntax for creating a table along with a full outer join statement, but I'm not entirely sure what it is if that's the case.[image: below]

```
CREATE TABLE SPSS as (SELECT SPSS_INPUT_TABLE.*, DIG_HISTORY.REPAIR_TYPE_DETAILS, 
DIG_HISTORY.DIG_COMPLETION_YEAR
FROM SPSS_INPUT_TABLE FULL OUTER JOIN
DIG_HISTORY ON SPSS_INPUT_TABLE.DISTANCE__M_=DIG_HISTORY.ILI_CHAINAGE 
ORDER by SPSS_INPUT_TABLE.DISTANCE__M_);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just append "WITH DATA" after the parenthesis. This tells dashDB to create the table and fill it with the data from the result set of your join. Alternatively when you specify "DEFINITION ONLY" it will only take the schema of the result set to define the new table but will not copy the result set content in.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like "WITH DATA", but I got a work around it by putting "WITH NO DATA" to get the headers and then have a following "INSERT INTO tableName3" to fill in the corresponding rows. It's a messy work around, but it's a work around.